# Hyperlink click method in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have one `UIWebView` in my iphone app and I have to detect on click method whenever user will click on any hyperlink.
I want to call one method when user will click on hyper link I know about the method

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

but it will be detected whenever any link will be loaded whether user has clicked or not on hyperlink but I want to call method only when user will click on any method.
Please get me out of this issue.
-Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `UIWebViewNavigationType`.

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSLog("User tapped a link.");
    }
}
```

See [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: Great answer! I also need this.